# Minimax and alpha beta use on board

Tags: chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I have a problem understading how does minimax actually work on board.
Let's suppose it's white turn. To get the best move possible do i need to apply minimax on every legal move generated by my move generator and then take the best score ?
Let's suppose now that i applied minimax on a single legal move of my pawn. As far as my understanding goes, minimax is a reccursive algorithm and now it will be applied to search the best move possible for the black side. At this point will it be applied on all the possible legal moves of the black side ?
If my understanding is wrong, would you please correct me using an exemple ? 
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose `you` are `maximizer` and `your opponent` is `minimizer`. I have painted some pictures below to explain how `minimax` works.
[image]

And now, suppose it is your turn, see the picture below.
[image]

From current state on the game board. You are trying to find the best move to get the best score for you, but it is depend on `your opponent's choices` so you have to assume that your opponent is going to the optimal moves to decrease your score as small as possible so that you can make your decision. So, at your opponent's turn, `the opponent` will chose the move that make your score as small as possible, so the graph will be as below:
[image]

Now, depend on the best moves that your opponent have generated, you can see that `2` is the best score which you can get (if your opponent is very optimal and intelligence). So you will chose the middle move.
[image]

Comment: @Zenith1996 Did you understand?